# Custom format with custom Multiples Excel

Tags: excel, format

I recently wanted to create an excel table to note all my electric components that I have so I can easily find the right component without searching every time for it.

The problem is, especially with capacitors, they come with a wide range of values generally for me between 220uF and 10pF, and I want to create a custom format to display the values properly in excel, for example if I put in a cell 0.00022 it shows 220uF or maybe 0.22mF (but 220uF is better) and not 2.2E-04 or any other format.

I tried the custom tool but I don't know how to add the micros, nanos and picos.

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions to the formatting, like:

```
[<0.00001] 0.00%%% "pF";[<0.001] 0.00% "uF";#
```

This will show 2.20%% uF in the cell (so you can multiply by using the percent sign, more details [here](https://chandoo.org/wp/custom-number-formats-multiply-divide-by-any-power-of-10/)).
Drawback: the percent signs are shown, and the Ctrl+J trick described on the link does not really work for me (and I personally find it as an ugly solution).
If I were you I'd add a new column called "Formatted" where I multiply the values with formulas. Like

```
=IF(A1<0.00001,A1*1000000 & "pF",IF(A1<0.001,A1*10000 & "uF"))
```

It's easier then to search in both columns (one is by formatted, like all "uF", other is by real Farad value. Also you could use the original column for sorting.